# Timescaledb ERROR: foreign keys to hypertables are not supported when trying to insert data

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, timescaledb

```
CREATE TABLE parent 
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    datecolumn TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, datecolumn),
    UNIQUE (id, datecolumn)
);

SELECT create_hypertable('parent','datecolumn');

CREATE TABLE child 
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    datecolumn TIMESTAMP,
    id_parent INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, datecolumn),
    UNIQUE (id_parent, datecolumn)
);

SELECT create_hypertable('child','datecolumn');

ALTER TABLE child 
    ADD CONSTRAINT child_Parent_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (id_parent, datecolumn) REFERENCES parent (id, datecolumn);
```

I am able to create a hypertable and at the same time able to establish a foreign key relationship. But, when I try to insert data, I face the below error

> ERROR:  foreign keys to hypertables are not supportedCONTEXT:  SQL statement " ALTER TABLE _timescaledb_internal._hyper_69_30_chunk ADD CONSTRAINT "30_10_child_Parent_fk " FOREIGN KEY ('child','datecolumn') REFERENCES public.parent('child','datecolumn')
>
> "PL/pgSQLfunction_timescaledb_internal.chunk_constraint_add_table_constraint(_timescaledb_catalog.chunk_constraint) line 58 at EXECUTEuery

I understand timescaledb's limitation on foreign key, but is there any work around for this problem?

Comment: Don't use TimescaleDB or live without a foreign key.

Comment: Unfortunately, per the documentation, there are some limitations on hypertables, including that foreign key constraints referencing hypertables are not supported. If that's the full design of the tables, it feels as though you're trying to achieve something that might be addressed in another way. For example, would a view of the hypertable fulfil your requirement?

Comment: Most TimescaleDB users who use FKs want to reference regular PostgreSQL tables not hypertables - that works fine (aka referencing "static" data from hypertables using FKs works properly) I'd be curious to know what's your use case (I'm guessing the tables you provided are just examples?) where you need FKs between two time-series tables